# Query from 2 MDB

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I'm a newbie of programming. I'm working on an old Visual Basic 6 Project, and I need to do a Query using 2 different MDB files.

So...at first I use the string connection to "catch" the files and Open the connection.

```
Public Sub QLeggi7(strQuery As String)
    If daEnv.rsLeggi7.State = adStateOpen Then
        daEnv.rsLeggi7.Close
    End If
    
    If strQuery <> "" Then
        daEnv.Commands("Leggi7").CommandText = strQuery
    End If
    
    daEnv.Leggi7
End Sub

 'STRINGA DI CONNESSIONE E APERTURA AL DATABASE ACCISE

daEnv.Connection2.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & App.path & "\" & "Accise.mdb;"
daEnv.Connection2.Open

'STRINGA DI CONNESSIONE E APERTURA DATABASE DAA
daEnv.Connection3.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & App.path & "\" & "daa.mdb;"
daEnv.Connection3.Open
```

then the Query

```
strqry = "SELECT * From MOVIMACCISE ,Tab_Testata_A"
```

And now i need to Sum all the values from the column called "C14" and i use this code

```
Call QLeggi7(strqry)

    If daEnv.rsLeggi7.RecordCount > 0 Then

        daEnv.rsLeggi7.MoveFirst
        Do Until daEnv.rsLeggi7.EOF
        LitriIdratiScarico = (LitriIdratiScarico + daEnv.rsLeggi7!MOVIMACCISE.C14)
        daEnv.rsLeggi7.MoveNext
Loop
End If

txLiBirraCarTOT.Text = CStr(LitriIdratiScarico)
```

But I recevie this error

[image: Software Error]

Do you know how Can i solve?

English:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query. Verify that it exists and that the name is spelled correctly

Comment: Please translate the error message to English and include it as text in your question. Instead of looping a recordset to Sum why not open the recordset with an aggregate SQL?

Answer (score 0):

First, somehow you don't have the table MOVIMACCISE attached. Why, we can't tell, but probably the connection is not established.

Next, if the field is named C14, this might read:

```
LitriIdratiScarico = (LitriIdratiScarico + daEnv.rsLeggi7!C14.Value)
```

But first, do establish the connection to the database and the table.